# Buffer around lines with rules or expressions

Tags: line, buffer, expression, rule-based

I need to create buffers around a layer of lines that represent infrastructures and they are symbolized according to the type (roads, railway, waterway and electric cables). Is there any way to create a buffer which uses a different expression for each type of infrastructure? If so, how and if possible could I use values from another layer field?
By the way, I am working in QGIS 3.16

Comment: Are you asking how to use `data defined override` in the buffer tool?

Comment: Yes. Although I've tried by simply symbolizing a buffer with the geometry generator as a possible solution

Comment: What is unclear about data defined override?

Comment: I'm not sure what data defined override is but I guess it's about that

Comment: Data defined override (accessible via the small stacked rectangles next to nearly every field in the GUI) let's you choose a field to use for e.g. buffering, or enter an expression to buffer by.

Comment: Ok. Then that's what I need, but the problem is in order to do the buffer I need to use the fields and values that are located in another layer

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if you provided one or two examples which show the connection between buffer-distance and features, to point out rules and/or categories.

Comment: Sorry, it is not a line layer but a polyogon that represents lines and what I need is to make buffers around each line which is a different infrastructure but the distance must be the calcule of some values that are in another layer (points). They are the height and rotor of wind turbines. Each value is not similar so I don't know how could relate the two layers

Comment: So you want to do planning for windfarms, esp. delivery & erection incl. free spaces in curves using GIS? Sorry, that's what CAD is there for.